# Exporting html table with formatted CSS into an Excel or PDF file in Javascript or Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, excel, html-table

I have tried several methods the Datatable method with a button click and also this Javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var tableToExcel = (function () {
    var uri = 'data:application/vnd.ms-excel;base64,',
        template = '<html xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40"><head><!--[if gte mso 9]><xml><x:ExcelWorkbook><x:ExcelWorksheets><x:ExcelWorksheet><x:Name>{worksheet}</x:Name><x:WorksheetOptions><x:DisplayGridlines/></x:WorksheetOptions></x:ExcelWorksheet></x:ExcelWorksheets></x:ExcelWorkbook></xml><![endif]--></head><body><table>{table}</table></body></html>',
        base64 = function (s) {
            return window.btoa(unescape(encodeURIComponent(s)))
        },
        format = function (s, c) {
            return s.replace(/{(\w+)}/g, function (m, p) {
                return c[p];
            })
        }
    return function (table, name) {
        if (!table.nodeType) table = document.getElementById(table)
        var ctx = {
            worksheet: name || 'Worksheet',
            table: table.innerHTML
        }
        window.location.href = uri + base64(format(template, ctx))
    }
})()
</script>
```

With this button:

```
<input type="button" onclick="tableToExcel('myTable', 'W3C Example Table')" value="Export to Excel">
```

Is it possible save also the formatted CSS table? I only formatted the tables at tr for example like this:

```
<tr class="wassat">
<td><a>280 Zzzap</a></td>
<td><a>Bally Astrocade</a></td>
<td><a>arc 4/10</a></td>
<td><a>badan</a></td>
<td><a>3/5</a></td>
<td><a>Rc</a></td>
<td><a>Arc</a></td>
<td><a>1978</a></td>
<td><a>Didam</a></td>
<td><a></a></td>

</tr>
```

the css code is like this

```
tr.wassat { background-color:#DF7401; }
```

I hope this is not a double post couldn`t find it in search.

Comment: http://datatables.net/extras/tabletools/ - have you tried this?

Comment: yes i did but it saves the Table normally without the formatted css and also as a csv but it can be loaded into excel as a excel Table

Answer (score 0):

TRY THIS:

```
var tableToExcel = (function () {
            var uri = 'data:application/vnd.ms-excel;base64,'
                , template = '<html xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40"><head><!--[if gte mso 9]><xml><x:ExcelWorkbook><x:ExcelWorksheets><x:ExcelWorksheet><x:Name>{worksheet}</x:Name><x:WorksheetOptions><x:DisplayGridlines/></x:WorksheetOptions></x:ExcelWorksheet></x:ExcelWorksheets></x:ExcelWorkbook></xml><![endif]--></head><body><table>{table}</table></body></html>'
                , base64 = function (s) { return window.btoa(unescape(encodeURIComponent(s))) }
                , format = function (s, c) { return s.replace(/{(\w+)}/g, function (m, p) { return c[p]; }) }
            return function (table, name) {
                if (!table.nodeType) table = document.getElementById(table)
                var ctx = { worksheet: name || 'Worksheet', table: table.innerHTML }
                var blob = new Blob([format(template, ctx)]);
                var blobURL = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);

                if (ifIE()) {
                    csvData = table.innerHTML;
                    if (window.navigator.msSaveBlob) {
                        var blob = new Blob([format(template, ctx)], {
                            type: "text/html"
                        });
                        navigator.msSaveBlob(blob, '' + name + '.xls');
                    }
                }
                else
                window.location.href = uri + base64(format(template, ctx))
            }
        })()

        function ifIE() {
            var isIE11 = navigator.userAgent.indexOf(".NET CLR") > -1;
            var isIE11orLess = isIE11 || navigator.appVersion.indexOf("MSIE") != -1;
            return isIE11orLess;
        }
```